# NGINX/PHP downloading instead of executing

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have an NGINX server with fastcgi/PHP running on it. I need to add userdirs to it, but I can't get PHP to execute the files - it just asks me if I want to download it. It does work without the userdir (e.g. it works on physibots.info/hugs.php, but not physibots.info/~kisses/hugs.php).

Config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name physibots.info;
    access_log  /home/virtual/physibots.info/logs/access.log;

    root /home/virtual/physibots.info/public_html;

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?\.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/$1/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /error.html/$uri?null;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Note:* I've also tried it without the first location block, with the "fastcgi_param" line in the second location block, and without it at all, and they all have the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was linking to /home/foo/public_html/~foo.  So, a circular symlink from /home/foo/public_html/~foo back to /home/foo/public_html works like a charm.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem before on another server. My issue was that the scripts containerd `<?`. Taking all of that and placing php after it (like this `<?php` ) anywhere it appears in the script executed the files instead of downloading them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, this script uses `<?php ?>` endings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the php location blocks:

```
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Btw - did you check that the `php.socket` actually exists?

Comment: It's in the server-wide conf file.  And, like I said, it works perfectly for the sites that have hostnames that are explicitly stated and the root domain.

Comment: What does the error log show for requests hitting `physibots.info/~kisses/hugs.php`? Just a guess, but I think this may be an issue with the way you're passing the file path and script name.

Comment: It shows nothing about the file requested.  The only messages in the error log are about missing favicons.  Also, nothing reported by PHP in the syslog according to the error log directives in php.ini.

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? If so, make sure `error_log` is enabled in  `php-fpm.conf`